# Self signed certificate not working on GlassFish server 4.0

Tags: ssl, glassfish, certificate, self-signed

I've created a self signed certificate and added it to keystore.jks, but once configured in the http-listener-2 via admin console it does not work. Default "s1as" certificate works properly btw.

Server information:

```
Install directory: C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.0\glassfish
Installed version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 (build 89)
```

What I have done:

Open a cmd as administrator

Add keytool to PATH

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin"
```

Generate key

```
C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.0\glassfish\domains\domain1\config>keytool -keysize
 2048 -genkey -alias autofirmado -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -validity 360
Introduzca la contraseña del almacén de claves:
¿Cuáles son su nombre y su apellido?
  [Unknown]:  Myname
¿Cuál es el nombre de su unidad de organización?
  [Unknown]:  test
¿Cuál es el nombre de su organización?
  [Unknown]:  test2
¿Cuál es el nombre de su ciudad o localidad?
  [Unknown]:  locality
¿Cuál es el nombre de su estado o provincia?
  [Unknown]:  province
¿Cuál es el código de país de dos letras de la unidad?
  [Unknown]:  es
¿Es correcto CN=Myname, OU=test, O=test2, L=locality, ST=province, C=es?
  [no]:  si

Introduzca la contraseña de clave para <autofirmado>
        (INTRO si es la misma contraseña que la del almacén de claves): <ENTER>
```

Verify new generated key is inside keystore.jks

```
C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.0\glassfish\domains\domain1\config>keytool -list -k
eystore keystore.jks -alias autofirmado -v
Introduzca la contraseña del almacén de claves:
Nombre de Alias: autofirmado
Fecha de Creación: 21-dic-2014
Tipo de Entrada: PrivateKeyEntry
...
```

Then configured http-listener-2:

```
alias: autofirmado
keystore: keystore.jks
truststore: cacerts.jks
```

Then restarted the server and tried to access through https localhost 8181 but I get the firefox message:

"The connection was interrupted"

If I configure the GlassFish server with the default "s1as" key it works properly.

Answer (score 2):

Since I have found this question due to another mistake I write here some possible causes of problems in similar situations.

## Wrong certificate name

This is the case of this question. I Chrome I had the following message:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

You have to set **CN=localhost** to get it working.

```
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  localhost
```

This is specified also in GlassFish Security Guide:

> For HTTPS hostname verification, it is important to ensure that the name of the certificate (CN) matches the fully-qualified hostname of your site (fully-qualified domain name). If the names do not match, clients connecting to the server will see a security alert stating that the name of the certificate does not match the name of the site.

## Wrong key algorithm

I used the `keytool -genkey` command without specifying the `-keyalg` option and this created a certificate with `SHA1withDSA`.

Chrome said `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` and in my server log I found

```java
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

I solved this specifying **`keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA`**

## Change also glassfish-instance certificate

From GlassFish Security Guide:

> DAS uses the `s1as` alias for SSL/TLS authentication and the
>   instances use the `glassfish-instance` alias

According to a comment on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29280729/771431) "If you change the s1as certificate, you will also need to change the glassfish-instance certificate".

## Wrong keystore file

Remember that:

- The `keystore.jks` file contains GlassFish Server certificate, including its **private key**.
- The `cacerts.jks` file contains the GlassFish Server trusted certificates, including **public keys** for other entities.

Sometimes the distraction can made you put the public key in the wrong file. This should be the correct sequence:

```sh
# Generate a key pair in keystore.jks
keytool -genkeypair -alias s1as -keystore keystore.jks -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -keyalg RSA
# Export the certificate
keytool -export -keystore keystore.jks -alias s1as -file s1as.cer -storepass changeit
# Import it into the truststore.jks
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -file s1as.cer -alias s1as -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass changeit
```

## How to check

This command shows information about certificates:

```sh
keytool -v -list -alias <the_alias> -keystore <filename>.jks
```

If you take a look to the original self-signed certificates provided by GlassFish you have:

- **CN**:

  - `Owner: CN=localhost` for `s1as`
  - `Owner: CN=localhost-instance` for `glassfish-instance`
- **RSA**: `Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA`
- **Entry type**:

  - `Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry` for `keystore.jks`
  - `Entry type: trustedCertEntry` for `cacerts.jks`