# Right way to configure Glassfish SSL certificate nickname?

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, glassfish-4, glassfish-4.1

Glassfish lets to set the SSL certificate nickname through its admin console as it is highlighted in the pic below:

[image: Glassfish Admin Console SSL Configuration UI]

But almost every tutorials in the web mention that it is necessary to replace all occurrences of the default SSL nickname (`s1as`) with the one will be used(i.e. `mydomain.com`) in the `domain.xml` file.

So what is the proper way of setting certificate nickname?

Comment: Hi @talha06, could you help me with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104301/glassfish-4-1-1-das-with-my-own-certificate-throws-j-security-check-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very likely that the admin console is just updating the domain.xml file anyway. In either case, it is good practice to avoid modifying the domain.xml file wherever possible. There is no official advice in the Security Guide for GF4 and the only mention of the certificate nickname is:

> If you enable secure admin on an SSL-enabled GlassFish Server
>   installation, secure admin uses the existing  value
>   as the DAS admin alias for secure admin.

https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/security-guide.pdf

Changing the nickname isn't actually necessary, from a functional perspective. When you import your key/cert to the keystores you can just use the same name to replace the existing cert, which is perfectly valid.

---

**Edit**: To change alias names with the `asadmin` command, you can use `enable-secure-admin` with either `--instancealias myNewAlias` or `--adminalias myOtherNewAlias` (or both).

The default for `adminalias` is `s1as` and the default for `instancealias` is `glassfish-instance`.

Comment: it did not work; after I replaced my certificate with the default `s1as`; I couldn't login to **Admin Console**, got `j_security_check` page and found this exception in the server log: `ssl_handshake`

Comment: That is because there is both a keystore and a truststore for GlassFish, and the Admin console effectively uses 2-way SSL authentication for the initial login. If you change the s1as certificate, you will also need to change the glassfish-instance certificate, i.e. import the root cert into truststore.jks and the server chain into keystore.jks. It can be tricky to get right if you're not familiar with it.

Comment: I've added some further explanation. If you want to read more, check the official guide I linked in my answer and see section 5-4 (page 80)

Comment: I followed steps you wrote & replaced both `s1as` & `glassfish-instance` certificates with my domain's certificate. SSL works now & but still I am not able to login to Admin Console. I get my admin password from `local-password` file & logged into the admin console. Then I changed admin password but still I can not login to admin console with my new password.

Comment: It's possible that you need to update the `secure-admin-principal` with the correct *distinguished name* of the new certificate. Fortunately, GF checks if this is needed and fills in the right value for you when you run `asadmin enable-secure-admin`. It doesn't matter if secure admin is already enabled, it will still work. If you like, you can check the **domain.xml** or **standalone.xml** file for `secure-admin-principal` before and after and see it get updated. HTH.

Comment: Hi @Mike could you help me with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104301/glassfish-4-1-1-das-with-my-own-certificate-throws-j-security-check-error

Answer (score 2):

**http-listener-2** is the default http listener (glassfish or payara) with ssl enabled on port 8181, if you have created another change for it in the bellow command.

```
asadmin set "configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.ssl.cert-nickname=yourNickName"
```