# Unable to login to Glassfish Console, but I can use asadmin

Tags: java, glassfish

Pretty much says it all, but when I try to log in to the Glassfish console I am get a "Error Authentication Failed Re-enter your username and password"

However when i use asadmin I am able to login, deploy, etc. it all works.

If there is a particular place I can alter the log level or a place I can look.

FYI part of the reason I think this happened is that I have changed the master password.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Exactly sure why it works, but I think it may be due to some cached values. I already had secure admin enabled when I stared the process of adding SSL certificates, and based on information in this post:
[Right way to configure Glassfish SSL certificate nickname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278152/right-way-to-configure-glassfish-ssl-certificate-nickname/29280729#29280729) I was able to find a solution.
With the server running Disable Secure Admin.
Restart Server
Enable Secure Admin
Restart Server.