# Glassfish 4.1.1 - DAS with my own certificate throws "j_security_check" error

Tags: java, security, ssl, https, glassfish

I have an instance of glassfish 4.1.1 running and I added my own certificate to my applications, until then everything is Ok..

But, when I tried to access the glassfish admin(DAS) the connection was unstrusted and the button to add exception disappears.

Then I found some interesting links talking about that, like :

- [Right way to configure Glassfish SSL certificate nickname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278152/right-way-to-configure-glassfish-ssl-certificate-nickname)

I tried this:

```
asadmin enable-secure-admin --adminalias=myNewAlias --instancealias myNewAlias
asadmin restart-domain domain1
```

This way the untrusted connection message disappears and the certicate properly appears, but when I try the authentication throw an error:

- https://myUrl:4848/j_security_check

According to the comments of the answer from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278152/right-way-to-configure-glassfish-ssl-certificate-nickname), it is very similar what that guy had but I could not solve it doing:

- Removing the s1as certificate from ~.gfclient/truststore
- Restart the domain with my new alias cert

**How could I change the s1as certificate properly? In order to my DAS works...**

I'am using Ubuntu 14 with java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.

Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:
[image]

The server log showing these lines:

> [2016-10-18T10:38:12.565+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] []
>   [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=51
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1476779892565] [levelValue: 1000] [[   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target;
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target; restRequest:
>   endpoint=https://localhost:4848/management/domain/anonymous-user-enabled
>   attrs={} method=GET]]

Comment: Are you actually adding your own trusted cert to the keystore and truststore, or just changing the alias?

Comment: Yes, I am adding my cert to cacerts and keystore inside : /domain1/config

Comment: I finally solved it, my cacerts still with the oldest s1as certificate and I dont realize.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally solved it, why it was happening? Using the @Mike explanation:

> That is because there is both a keystore and a truststore for
>   GlassFish, and the Admin console effectively uses 2-way SSL
>   authentication for the initial login. If you change the s1as
>   certificate, you will also need to change the glassfish-instance
>   certificate

**In my case I was trying to use my own certificate but I did not delete the oldest certificates properly on cacerts.jks and keystore.jks files.**

I was running the code bellow without firstly remove the s1as and glassfish-instance from files, that was my wrong step...

```
asadmin enable-secure-admin --adminalias=myNewAlias --instancealias myNewAlias
```

---

To your Domain Administration Server (DAS) on Glassfish 4.1.1 run with your own certificate you must follow these steps:

**1) Insert your own certificate into cacerts.jks and keystore.jks files:**

In my case I am using certificate pkcs12:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore myOwnCert.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass changeit -alias myOwnAlias

keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit -destkeystore cacerts.jks -srckeystore myOwnCert.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass changeit -alias myOwnAlias
```

If you have another kind of certificate you must search how to insert inside this two files your certificate type:

> $GLASSFISH_HOME/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks - truststore -
>   holding all the public keys
>       $GLASSFISH_HOME/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks - keystore - holding all the private keys

References:

Session 6. Security configuration before first startup: 
https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-41-on-ubuntu

http://peter-butkovic.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/glassfish-default-keystore-and.html

https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html?jn9ed3e997=3

https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/security-guide.pdf

**2) Delete the oldest self-signed certificates:**

By default, when you run the command enabled-secur-admin the certificate assigned to this instance is **s1as** and the public is **glassfish-instance**, as explained by @Mike into another [stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278152/right-way-to-configure-glassfish-ssl-certificate-nickname) the certificates remains even if you force to run with another certificate. Delete both using these commands:

```
#Restart your domain without secure-admin
$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin disable-secure-admin


#Go to your domain config folder to remove the certificates:
cd $GLASSFISH_HOME/domains/domain1/config/
keytool -delete -alias s1as -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit
keytool -delete -alias glassfish-instance -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit
keytool -delete -alias glassfish-instance -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass changeit
keytool -delete -alias s1as -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass changeit
```

References:

Thanks @Mike: [Right way to configure Glassfish SSL certificate nickname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278152/right-way-to-configure-glassfish-ssl-certificate-nickname)

https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/security-guide.pdf (page ~80)

**3) Restart the security-admin with your own alias set on the first step**

```
$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin enable-secure-admin --adminalias=myOwnAlias --instancealias myOwnAlias

$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin restart-domain
```

**In theory, it is done, You'll be able to access the DAS with your own certificate... ;)**